# Using a flexible fittings for direct to sink drain commercially legal?

Tags: plumbing

[image]

Came across this on a commercial sink. Is using a flexible fitting on a sink drain for commercial or residential legal? I personally like the idea of it. Since the grip is greater to hang onto the pipe versus a slip fit. The trap was at the end of a three series sink. Location is Olympia Wa Thurston County using IBC and WA

Comment: That may depend on location. City/State/Country?

Comment: Eli - Welcome to DIY. I think you'll be glad to know we encourage fact-based answers over opinions. We also try to strike a positive tone in questions and answers. Hope some of our dedicated members can guide you to the cites you need.

Comment: You appear to be using "scupper" in a manner not consistent with the definition of scupper as found in a dictionary, unless you mean that the pipe just runs though the wall and dumps water outside, not into a sewer, which would be highly unusual in any place with code (and codes vary from place to place, so not specifying yours means nobody knows which code to refer to anyway.) So you (and anyone else) probably won't find much for code references including "scupper."

Comment: Sink scupper appears to describe a sink drain with a built in strainer.  These look like ordinary drains to me, but shrug.  Plumbing has some oddly named parts here and there.  Incidentally, if you don't want to tell us where you live, you could as an alternative tell us which code is relevant.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to ruffle any feathers with the way I phrased the question.  Guess I was ruffled because I got an earful from both sides of the fence and everyone had a strong opinion about it with no citations. The sink in questions is in City of Olympia Thurston County Washington which to my knowledge uses the IBC.and the WAC Washington State Code amendments.

Comment: It likely depends on the type of material of the piping. I asked this question for PVC to PVC connections above ground (https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119494/per-irc-are-flexible-pvc-couplings-ever-allowed-to-be-used-above-ground-for-pvc) and did not get any definitive answers in the affirmative with code references.