# Why is this Ptrap installed in this location?

Tags: plumbing, p-trap

Here is a recent installation done to my home

[image: p trap]

I took this one before i drained the water:
[image: p trap submerged in water]

Note that this a p-trap that is installed at the external wall of my house. It would be in line with the p-trap of the kitchen sink, which very close at the other side of the wall.

My questions are:

- Is this a mistake?
- If so, what damage it can do?
- what is the correct part that needs to be installed?

**update**: I have rebuild it myself. here is the result, what do you think?
[image]

**update 2** posted a folow up question: [what is the correct procedure to patch up cinder block hole with plumbing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/193721/what-is-the-correct-procedure-to-patch-up-cinder-block-hole-with-plumbing)

Comment: Are you sure it is a ptrap ?  I can not see in the hole, How does it connect to drain down ? . the sanitary tee is upside down. Why was this work done ? More info is needed.

Comment: it is yes a p-trap. its diffecult to see the bottom half because it is submurhed from a leak

Comment: @AlaskaMan, I have just drained some of the water and took more photos

Comment: That can not possibly be a drain from a sink inside on the other side of the wall as it does not drain down. Have you asked the plumber or person  who installed it  ?  It makes no sense with the info you have given us. It may be a drain for some thing above but again the santee is upside down. What fixtures might   above that the vertical pipe would be coming from ?

Comment: I have lost contact with the plumber who installed it, but this is the exact situation in my home. the pipe from the top is where the water from the kitchen sink are coming, after a p-trap. the lower pipe goes to the sewer. it seems to be an installation mistake, I just want to verify

Comment: There is not really enough information for us to say. In your question you made sound as if the sink was directly on the other side of this Ptrap. Unless there is some fixture above that does not have a trap then i see no reason for one here and i question the knowledge level of the installer since the san-tee is upside down. You need a plumber to come and look at it or talk to the installer. We can only guess. I see no reason to think damage could result except that water can sit and stagnate in the clean out of the upside down san-tee, that should be fixed.

Comment: That’s not the right place for a trap to be except for a bathtub. It looks intentional to me so not a mistake, someone probably had plugged drain issues and this was their way of fixing it. Definitely a diy not correct with the T in backwards and not a good place as it will probably freeze if you have freezing conditions in your area.

Comment: I agree with Ed Beal that it looks like a diy job gone wrong where someone wanted the upside-down sanitary tee for its access as a cleanout to go up with a rooter occasionally and then used the P-trap simply because it looped back to the original pipe location rather than knocking another block out of the wall (or another better solution for the problem that could only be determined with more information).

Comment: OP states that the vertical pipes continue on down. The photo is not accurately showing the vertical pipe continuation and how the sink drain is connecting to the vertical. We need the photo to show how the sink drain pipe is connecting to the vertical. We are assuming that the joint below the Tee is the connection of the sink.   I would guess that it is another Tee that connects to the sink drain, and the long part of the tee is vertical and continue the pipe further down.

Comment: Also, depending on the applicable plumbing code where you live, that black coupling to join two sections of PVC pipe could also technically be a code violation: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/119494/36011 A PVC slip coupling is a suitable alternative in repair of PVC to PVC joints.

Comment: Do you know where from and what is connected at the upper end of the vertical pipe in the wall?  It's strange that the pipe is only a 2" pipe.

Comment: it its directly connected to a vent in the roof, and also takes wastewater from the kitchen sink, dishwasher and washer

Comment: Yes, much cleaner look.  the curve of the 90 from vertical to house is in correct direction.